# Dimensions of double integrals as area

Tags: calculus, integration

When calculating double integrals using a function $f(x,y)$ we are able to calculate the volume under the function. we are also able to calculate the area bound by the limits if $f(x,y)=1$.

But I am unsure as to how this affects the dimensionality. Wouldn't it just be the volume of the object with a cross section of the the area with a height of $1$?

I understand that it would be the same in magnitude due to multiplying the area by $1$. But wouldn't it be of the wrong dimension? $\text{units}^3$ rather than $\text{units}^2$?

Comment: You can also think about $f$ as a _density_. Then computing $\iint f \mathrm{d}A$ is the same as computing the _mass_ of the object. In the case where the density is $1$, we have the mass equals the area (and we're using the density to do the unit conversion).